# QuickLook Crashing

Tags: macos, mac, finder, quicklook

I recently installed an SSD (m4 crucial latest firmware) with TRIM enabled on my late 2011 MBP 13".
I did a clean install of Mountain Lion 10.8.1, enabled FileVault 2 and everything was working fine for about 2 weeks until Finder just started randomly killing itself every time I mounted a DMG or just launched some random app. 

At the time I was getting this error:

> com.apple.quicklook.satellite[205]: [QL] Using too much memory (308
>   MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.

Backed up all my files manually and did another clean install. 
Installed a few applications, re-enabled FileVault, waited 2 days, everything was running fine. 
Decided it was time to copy my files back over. 
Whilst copying over Ethernet with Wifi enabled, I disabled the wifi, Finder hangs had to hard reset.
On reboot - error was back:

> 12/09/2012 23:24:27.883 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[172]: [QL] Using
>   too much memory (300 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting
>   immediately to clean up.
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:29.883 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[172]: [QL] Using
>   too much memory (616 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting
>   immediately to clean up.
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:29.943 com.apple.launchd[1]:
>   (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D[172])
>   Exited: Killed: 9
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:29.943 com.apple.launchd[1]:
>   (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D)
>   Throttling respawn: Will start in 2 seconds
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:33.509 awacsd[69]: Exiting
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:35.559 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100002
>   created
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:36.108 com.apple.quicklook.satellite[205]: [QL] Using
>   too much memory (308 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting
>   immediately to clean up.
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:36.129 com.apple.launchd[1]:
>   (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.DED6F2A5-B4D3-44C7-9EF6-86EF86AE217D[205])
>   Exited: Killed: 9
>
> 12/09/2012 23:24:39.824 com.apple.launchd[1]:
>   (com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication[108]) Exit timeout
>   elapsed (20 seconds). Killing

I cannot find anything similar on Google and for the life of me cannot figure out what is wrong. 
It's giving me the same error on every reboot and every 3-7 minutes. It's only matter of time I suspect before Finder starts going nuts. It's also worth mentioning that very few applications are installed at the moment.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `qlmanage -r` or moving Quick Look plugins out of ~/Library/QuickLook/ and /Library/QuickLook/?

Comment: Thanks for that Lri, unfortunately that hasn't solved it :S
I checked the paths you mentioned but the QuickLook folder isn't present in ~/Library only in /Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the problem turned out to be quite a large CSV file that had been created on an old version of excel that quicklook constantly attempted to generate a preview for. Strange indeed.